# How can I use frida to hook a c method with variable argument list

Tags: c, frida

I want to use frida to hook a c method with variable argument list like this:

```
int execl （const char *filename， const char *arg0， ...）
```

But I didn't know how to get variable argument list content and put it to another c method in frida.

Comment: Have you checked that `execl` isn't implemented by using `execv` (which should be easier to hook)?

Comment: If you hook the method you are getting the `args` array with al parameters. Not sure if you can rely on the length of this args array, otherwise go therough the arguments and test them is they are a valid CString. An example how to create a new var arg argument I posted last week in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72880066/150978).