# Running Frida on Android Executable [ELF] with Custom Arguments

Tags: android, hook, elf, inject, frida

i want to run frida on Android executable[elf] with argument.

like this is an cpp

```
#include <iostream>

#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    printf("ARG 1 -> %s\n",argv[1]);

    printf("ARG 2 -> %s\n", argv[2]);

    system("echo hello");

    return 0;

}
```

now i compile this as "mycpp" and paste the binary to /data/local/tmp with 777 permission im using Frida-inject

so i will running frida as

```
su -c /data/local/tmp/frida -f /data/local/tmp/mycpp -s /data/local/tmp/systemhook.js
```

here is systemhook.js

```
Interceptor.attach(Module.findExportByName(null, "system"), {
    onEnter: function (args) {
        console.log("CMD USED -> " + Memory.readUtf8String(args[0]));
    }
});
```

it will work and hook the system call but there will no argument sended to the cpp, both argv[1] and argv[2] will be null .

i want to send both argument according to me in the frida executing command [not a hook for int main],

Like on executing frida with js and process it also takes arg

I have tried this one but dosent work both arg are still null.

```
su -c /data/local/tmp/frida -f /data/local/tmp/mycpp -s /data/local/tmp/systemhook.js arg1 arg2
```

is this is possible?? if yes then please provide me an example

Comment: I would recommend to load the created binary into a decompiler like Ghidra or IDA Pro to see the actual code that is executed. Having a C source code of a program does not mean you understand what is actually executed in the compiled version.

Comment: Regarding your `argv` problem please see my question and answer https://stackoverflow.com/q/72871352/150978

Comment: @Robert this is just a example code, i just want to pass argument while hooking with frida, this isn't the real program which im trying to hook  stackoverflow.com/q/72871352/150978 i have seen this and i have also mentioned in post it dosent work with frida-inject the arg is still null and i dont want to hook main function, cause the binary which im trying is obfuscated and dosent have any 'main' function

Comment: BTW: In your frida call you use the option `-s` which is unknown to me and undocumented in "frida --help" what does it do? Usually if you want to provide a script file you use `-l scriptfile.js`. Also I would recommend to separate the su call from the frida call just to make sure it is not su messing up the arguments.

Comment: @Robert i have mentioned im using frida-inject not frida server